# How to get the Monday of the current week (or previous week in some cases) regardless of the week starts on Sunday or Monday

Tags: javascript, date

I have `let today = new Date()` object. I need to get the Monday of the current week regardless if the week starts on Sunday or Monday. If the week starts on a Sunday and the `today` is Sunday I need to get the Monday on the previous week. Sunday should always be the last day. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Now I use this, which at least works fine when the week starts on Monday.

```js
// Get the monday date of current week
function getMondayOfCurrentWeek(d) {

  const date = new Date(d);
  const day = date.getDay(); // Sunday - Saturday : 0 - 6

  //  Day of month - day of week (-6 if Sunday), otherwise +1
  const diff = date.getDate() - day + (day === 0 ? -6 : 1);

  return new Date(date.setDate(diff));
}

console.log(
  getMondayOfCurrentWeek(new Date(2022,3,3)).toDateString()
);
```

Comment: The Country/Locale timezone of the user.

Comment: Why `new Date(date.setDate(diff))`? You can do `date.setDate(diff); return date;`

Comment: The OP code is unaffected by regional settings or user preferences of the host, it's a plain mathematical calculation applied to the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: It will return a date object as well? Thanks, it is maybe better.

Comment: Yep, thanks for helping me sort this out. Now I see more clearly that it is not in this function my time zone-related issue lies. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RobG thanks for giving me a perfect usecase for the comma operator `return date.setDate(diff), date;`

Comment: @mplungjan—great idea, I'll use that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code DOES get the previous Monday on a Sunday

What does "If the week starts on a Sunday" mean to your?

In JS Sunday is the 0th or first day

```js
// Get the monday date of current week
function getMondayOfCurrentWeek(d) {
  const date = new Date(d);
  const day = date.getDay(); // Sunday - Saturday : 0 - 6
  //  Day of month - day of week (-6 if Sunday), otherwise +1
  const diff = date.getDate() - day + (day === 0 ? -6 : 1);
  return date.setDate(diff), date;
}

console.log(getMondayOfCurrentWeek(new Date()).toDateString() )

console.log(getMondayOfCurrentWeek(new Date(2022,3,3,15,0,0,0)).toDateString() ); // Sunday 3rd of April 2022
```

Comment: When writing dates to the SO console it's nicer to use *toDateString* otherwise it shows as for *toISOString* which isn't that friendly.

Comment: Yep thanks for helping me sort this out. Now I see more clearly that it is not in this function my time zone-related issue lies. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DianaNilsson För al del :)